# new value not inserted in my user interface when adding new object

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add an  contact object and the way I do it is when the user hits add button in the menu bar; this is how I do it.

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_contact:
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                ContactLab.get(getActivity()).addContact(contact);
                updateUI();
                mCallbacks.onContactSelected(contact);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_edit:

                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                ContactLab crimeLab = ContactLab.get(getActivity());
                crimeLab.deleteContact(mContact);

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I have the following fragment

```
public class ContactListFragment extends Fragment {

   // private static final String SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE = "subtitle";

    private static final String ARG_CRIME_ID = "crime_id";
    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private ContactAdapter mAdapter;
    public Contact mContact;
    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Required interface for hosting activities.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        void onContactSelected(Contact contact);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        }

        updateUI();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }


    private void updateSubtitle() {
        ContactLab crimeLab = ContactLab.get(getActivity());
        int contactCount = crimeLab.getContacts().size();
        String subtitle = getString(R.string.subtitle_format, contactCount);


        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
    }

    public void updateUI() {
        ContactLab crimeLab = ContactLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Contact> contacts = crimeLab.getContacts();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(contacts);
            mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.setContacts(contacts);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

        updateSubtitle();
    }

    private class ContactHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {



        private TextView mTitleTextView;


        public ContactHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_content, parent, false));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content_name);

        }

        public void bind(Contact contact) {
            mContact = contact;
            mTitleTextView.setText(mContact.getName());

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCallbacks.onContactSelected(mContact);
        }
    }

    private class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactHolder> {

        private List<Contact> mContacts;

        public ContactAdapter(List<Contact> crimes) {
            mContacts = crimes;
        }

        @Override
        public ContactHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            return new ContactHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ContactHolder holder, int position) {
            Contact contact=mContacts.get(position);
            holder.bind(contact);
        }



        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mContacts.size();
        }

        public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
            mContacts = contacts;
        }
    }
```

and then I start the above fragment from the following activity fragment

```
public class ContactListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity
        implements ContactListFragment.Callbacks, ContactFragment.Callbacks {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new ContactListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResId() {
        return R.layout.activity_masterdetail;
    }
    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(Contact contact) {
        if (findViewById(R.id.detail_fragment_container) == null) {
            Intent intent = ContactPagerActivity.newIntent(this, contact.getIDD());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Fragment newDetail = ContactFragment.newInstance(contact.getId());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.detail_fragment_container, newDetail)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    public void onContactUpdated(Contact crime) {
        ContactListFragment listFragment = (ContactListFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        listFragment.updateUI();
    }
}
```

could any one show me whre I am doing wrong because I see the followoig error in my log

```
Process: com.bignerdranch.android.adressbook, PID: 28871
                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.bignerdranch.android.adressbook.Contact.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                         atcom.bignerdranch.android.adressbook.ContactFragment.onCreateView(ContactFragment.java:82)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
```